# Cannot add multiple OR clauses to Sqlite parameter

Tags: c#, sqlite

Using Sqlite (.NET), I have a statement:

```
Select * FROM vwTable WHERE id = 1
```

Adding the clause as a parameter works fine, ie:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select * FROM vwTable WHERE id = @ids";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ids", "1");
```

However, adding multiple clauses, as you'd do here:

```
Select * FROM vwTable WHERE id = 1 OR id = 2
```

Does not work as a parameter:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select * FROM vwTable WHERE id = @ids";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ids", "1 OR id = 2");
```

To clarify, I know the query can be hardcoded, but the multiple WHERE parameters will be dynamically generated elsewhere and could be any length.

Comment: The WHERE should be generated with the SELECT statement. You should pass all the criteria to the method responsible for building the SQL statement. Use the criteria to build each part of the WHERE clause.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use `IN` operator:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select * FROM vwTable WHERE id IN (@ids)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ids", string.Join(",", idList);
```

Comment: Does this really work in SQlite? I just tried it in SQL Server and it threw an exception when I calling `datareader.Read()` saying it couldn't convert a nvarchar (from string.join) to an int (ID column).